# Microsoft Edge - the best way/utility to reverse engineer extensions assembly code

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I need to understand how Microsoft Edge/Firefox/Chrome works for extension installation.
Firefox and Chrome are easy to work with, as they are open source, honor and praise for them! :)
But there are problems with Microsoft Edge

I am using WinDbg - it's pretty common and allows to debug internals.
Particularly, a very interesting part for me what happens on the application's exit, start and turning on and off our non-store custom extension.

Problem: there is too much code and it's not easy to find out that particular code is required to be debugged.

Before M.E. will move to chromium we have to do this kind of reverse engineering.

Thank you, guys! :)

UPD: I'am thinking about adding C++ tag, but don't know whether it's a good idea.

UPD 2:
I don't need utilities, software recommendations, rather techniques that allow understanding vast amount of assembly code.

Comment: Hello! This question doesnt fit the stackoverflow.com requirements as it asks for a tool recommendation. Instead you've got the software recommendations stack exchange place which is built for this aim. Regards :-)

Comment: okay let me move there :) thanks for recommendation